# adding bluetooth or other access allow in setting for your app

Tags: swift4, ios11, core-bluetooth, appsettings

My app uses **Bluetooth** and I want to show the **access permission** on app **setting**. how can I add Bluetooth or other access permission, here based on my requirement? like below Instagram

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

In p.list file add Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) Bluetooth Peripheral use</string>
```

Now Bluetooth appears in Settings

Comment: it did come you sure Bluetooth option comes, as I never seen any app where I can see Bluetooth option in app settings ?

Comment: as it will be listed in Settings -> Privacy -> Bluetooth Sharing

Comment: Nope! not listed in Settings -> Privacy -> Bluetooth Sharing